# Show that there exists a polynomial such that..

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So let $f \in C[a,b]$ be continuously differentiable and let $\epsilon > 0$. Show that there is a polynomial $p$ such that $\lVert f - p \lVert_{\infty} < \epsilon $ and $\lVert f' - p'\lVert_{\infty} <\epsilon$

Here's my approach:

Using the Weierstrass approximation to $f'$, we have that there exists a polynomial $q(x)$ such that $\lVert f' - q\lVert_{\infty}$

Let $p$ be a polynomial such that $p' = q$

Now I'm just stuck here, how would I continue?

Answer (score 3):

We have $f(x)-p(x) = f(a)-p(a) + \int_a^x (f'(t)-p'(t)) dt$, so
$|f(x)-p(x)| \le |f(a)-p(a)| + (b-a) \|f'-p'\|_\infty$ or
$\|f-p\|_\infty \le |f(a)-p(a)| + (b-a) \|f'-p'\|_\infty$.

Note that $p(x) = p(a) + \int_a^x p'(t) dt$ is a polynomial and you can choose
$p(a)$ however you wish.

Comment: I'm guessing this $x$ and $0$ are in $[a, b]$ correct? This is the way I would have approached it based off the hint provided except using $a$ and $b$ instead. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you need to show that the bound holds for all $x \in [a,b]$ (I had zero instead of $a$ by mistake above). The point is choose $p'$ first, then set $p(0) = f(0)$.

Comment: In all uses, zero should be a, right?

Comment: @Belgi: Yes indeed, I completely missed all zeros as parameters. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** how could we get that polynomial $p$? Think [Fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Note that you were correct to start with the approximation to $f'$, rather than the approximation to $f$.

Comment: Ah, fundamental theorem of calculus... Completely forgot about that theorem... Thanks, I think I can go from there!